# Initializing scalars with braces

Tags: c++, c, initialization, language-lawyer, list-initialization

In C and C++, one can initialize arrays and structs using braces:

```
int a[] = {2, 3, 5, 7};
entry e = {"answer", 42};
```

However, in [a talk from 2007](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OioZ78jnlM), Bjarne mentions that this syntax also works for scalars. I tried it:

```
int i = {7};
```

And it actually works! What is the rationale behind allowing the initialization of scalars with braces?

Note: I am specifically *not* talking about C++11 uniform initialization. This is good old C89 and C++98.

Comment: It's just part of the grammar of C++. Allowing all objects to be initialised this way is more consistent and probably simifies the implementation.

Comment: which pre C++11 compiler did you try?

Comment: Similar topic : [Braces around string literal in char array declaration valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147264/braces-around-string-literal-in-char-array-declaration-valid-e-g-char-s)

Comment: @rhalbersma Nothing fancy, just current gcc on Linux (yes, gcc, not g++). And also Visual Studio 2012, with does not support uniform initialization yet. So it can't be that.

Comment: I am pretty much sure You must have but just to confirm, have you compiled with `-pedantic`? Maybe it is just an compiler extension.

Comment: @Alok Just tried `gcc -pedantic`, and it still works.

Comment: @AlokSave: It IS allowed by C++03. I know this. I don't doubt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the rationale behind allowing the initialization of scalars with braces?

`int` is POD. So the brace initialization is allowed in case of `int` (and for all build-in types), as it makes the initialization-syntax *consistent* with other PODs.

Also, I guess whatever *rationale* behind C++11 Uniform Initialization Syntax are, are also (partially) applicable to this syntax allowed by C++03. It is just C++03 didn't extend this to include non-pod types such as the standard containers.

I can see one place where this initialization is helpful in C++03.

```
template<typename T>
void f()
{
    T  obj = { size() } ; //T is POD: built-in type or pod-struct
    //code
}
```

Now this can be instantiated with `struct` which begins with a suitable member, as well as any arithmetic type:

```
struct header
{ 
    size_t size; //it is the first member
    //...
};

f<header>(); //body becomes : header obj = { size(); }; which is fine
f<size_t>(); //body becomes : size_t obj = { size(); }; which is fine
```

Also note that POD, whether struct or built-in types, can also be initialized uniformly as:

```
header h = header(); //value-initialized
int    i = int();    //value-initialized
```

So I believe *one* reason is consistency!

Answer (score 4):

The rationale is not mentioned, but from a [2005 C++ Standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf), **8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]**, clause 14

If T is a scalar type, then a declaration of the form
`T x = { a };`
is equivalent to
`T x = a;`

Note that the C++ 98 Standard only allows brace initializers for copy-initialization `T x = { a }`, and not for direct initialization `T x { a }`, for which only `T x(a)` works.

**UPDATE**: see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462513/gcc-warning-braces-around-scalar-initializer)

Answer (score 1):

C++ probably inherited this from C. In C the main reason is to have a unique initilizer syntax, in particular for a default initializer. In C the default initializer is `{0}`.