# Wrong overload called when constructing from initializer_list inside parentheses

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, language-lawyer, clang++

I always thought that when I use initializer list C++ syntax like:

```
something({ ... });
```

it's always clear to the compiler that I want to call the overload taking an `std::initializer_list`, but it seems this is not so clear for MSVC 2015.

I tested this simple code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace testing {
  template<typename T>
  struct Test {
    Test() {
      printf("Test::Test()\n");
    }

    explicit Test(size_t count) {
      printf("Test::Test(int)\n");
    }

    Test(std::initializer_list<T> init) {
      printf("Test::Test(std::initializer_list)\n");
    }

    T* member;
  };

  struct IntSimilar {
    int val;

    IntSimilar() : val(0) {}
    IntSimilar(int v) : val(v) {}

    operator int() {
      return val;
    }
  };
}

int main() {
    testing::Test<testing::IntSimilar> obj({ 10 });
    return 0;
}
```

[Run](http://%20ideone.com/fj4NvT)

and in GCC 6.3 it works as expected, calling `Test::Test(std::initializer_list)`

but in MSVC 2015 this code calls `Test::Test(int)`.

It seems MSVC can somehow ignore the `{}` and choose an invalid/unexpected overload to call.

What does the Standard say about this situation? Which version is valid?

Can anybody test this and confirm whether or not this issue remains in MSVC 2017?

Comment: Which version of the standard do you use?

Comment: Community 2015 Version 14.0.25123.0 Update 2

Comment: No, which version of C++ standard you are compiling for? Is it C++14? C++17? C++11?

Comment: Under MSVC 2017 constructor Test::Test(int) is invoked too. You can check it using this page https://godbolt.org/.

Comment: I don't know any option to switch in Visual Studio to choose "standard version", it's not gcc, I'm linking with standard platform toolset v140. Options->C/C++->Language does not provide too many options and non of them is standard version. I far as I know MSVC does not provide such option...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490614.aspx

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o The document is old. Watch latest version here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o good to know. Switching between std:c++14 and std:c++latest has no any affect, MSVC choose Test(size_t count) anyway.

Comment: @yumetodo the link I provided refers to the version used by the OP

Comment: The behaviour of list initialization from one element changed several times over the 2011 - 2017 period

Answer (score 4):

> Which version is valid?

According to my understanding of the standard, **the GCC is *right*.**

> What does standard says about this situation?

What you do when you are writing `Test obj1({10});` is [*direct-initializing*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) an object of type `Test` with the expression `{ 10 }`. During overload resolution, the compiler has to decide which constructor to call. According to [16.3.3.2 § 3 (3.1.1) [over.ics.rank]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> *list-initialization* sequence `L1` is a better conversion sequence than list-initialization sequence `L2` if `L1` converts to
>   `std::initializer_list<X>` for some `X` and `L2` does not [...]

The standard also provides the example

```
void f1(int);                                 // #1
void f1(std::initializer_list<long>);         // #2
void g1() { f1({42}); }                       // chooses #2
```

This is the point where VS & clang differ from GCC: while all three will yield the same result in this particular example, changing it to

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { A(int) { } };
void f1(int) { std::cout << "int\n"; }                                // #1
void f1(std::initializer_list<A>) { std::cout << "list\n"; }          // #2

int main() {
    f1({42});
}
```

will let [clang chose the `int`-constructor](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1p9MpmsK43eTrWht), moaning about the unnecessary braces around the literal `42` (which seems to be just in the standard for legacy reasons, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232184/initializing-scalars-with-braces)) rather than checking if the `{ 42 }` list sequence really cannot be converted to `std::initializer_list<A>`.

Note however that writing `Test obj1{ 10 };` will lead to a different evaluation: According to the rules of [*list-initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> - Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
>   - All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type std::initializer_list

So the `initializer_list` constructor is taken for a special overload resolution stage considering only `initializer_list` constructors before the normal overload resolution is applied, as demonstrated in the famous `std::vector`-gotcha:

```
// will be a vector with elements 2, 0 rather than a vector of size 2 with values 0, 0
std::vector<int> v{ 2, 0 };
```

The fact that in both cases the standard decides to use the `initializer_list` constructor is a consistent choice, but technically, the reason for chosing it is quite different under the hood.

Comment: Good answer. The `f1({42});` example confirms what should happen.

Comment: Sounds correct. Hopefully some people who are registered on the MSVC and Clang bugtrackers will see this!

Comment: Pedantic point: `{10}` is not an expression, however it is an *expression-list* grammatically (which is either a list of expressions, or a *braced-init-list*)

Answer (score 2):

**GCC is wrong here**.

Indeed due to the parentheses it's *direct-initialization* so "normal" overloading rules apply, however, [[over.ics.rank]/3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.1) talk about this situation:

```
void f1(int);                                 // #1
void f1(std::initializer_list<long>);         // #2
void g1() { f1({42}); }                       // chooses #2
```

Whereas in *our* situation we have this:

```
struct IntSimilar { IntSimilar(int); };

void f1(size_t);                              // #1
void f1(std::initializer_list<IntSimilar>);   // #2
void g1() { f1({10}); }                       // chooses ?
```

And there is another rule, [[over.ics.rank]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#2) just before [over.ics.rank]/3:

> — a standard conversion sequence is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion

In order to invoke `Test(initializer_list<IntSimilar>)` a *user-defined conversion* is required (`int` to `IntSimilar`).
But there is a better viable alternative, specifically just an *integer conversion* from `int` to `size_t`. That is possible because a scalar, such as an `int`, can be list-initialized from a *braced-init-list* with a single `int` element. See [[dcl.init.list]/3.9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.9):

> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type E and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from that element ...

clang will in fact tell you exactly that (while selecting the `int` overload):

```
    warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
```

If you want to suppress automatic unwrapping of single-value *braced-init-list*s, either use *list-initialization* or wrap it into another *braced-init-list*:

```
    testing::Test<testing::IntSimilar> obj { 10 };
    testing::Test<testing::IntSimilar> obj({{10}});
```

- will select the `initializer_list<T>` overload everywhere.

Comment: Section 3.9 is never entered for this case. `T obj({ 10 })` is not "list initialization of an object or reference of type T".  (`T obj{10}` or `T obj = {10}` would be).  Instead, start at the top of [dcl.init]. Point 17 (in the standard version you linked) ,  we go down to 17.6.2 which specifies that applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen by overload resolution.  Point 17.1 does not apply because the initializer `({10})` is not a non-parenthesized braced-init-list.

Comment: I never said that `T` was initialized from `{ 10 }`. What I meant was that a temporary `int` was initialized from `{ 10 }`.

Comment: Corresponding GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99273