# Overload resolution between constructors from initalizer_list and from a value requiring conversion, compilers diverge

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, initializer-list, overload-resolution

In the following code, `struct A` has two constructors: `A(int)` and `A(std::initializer_list<char>)`. Then an object of the struct is created with `A({0})`:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct A {
    int a;
    constexpr A(int) { a = 1; } 
    constexpr A(std::initializer_list<char>) { a = 2; }
};

static_assert( A({0}).a == 2 );
```

It turns out that GCC and Clang prefer here the constructor from `initializer_list` (despite `int` argument has to be converted in `char`) and the whole program is accepted, but MSVC selects `A(int)` constructor, failing the `static_assert`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qx7W417Mv

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Brace-enclosed lists (even with only a single element) should be considered an `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Similar demo: https://godbolt.org/z/fnGTdGscK. If the template argument of `std::initializer_list` is changed to `int`, then MSVC agrees with GCC.

Comment: Possibly relevant standard section with a similar example: http://eel.is/c++draft/over#ics.rank-3.1.

Comment: Relevant (possibly even duplicate; but with user-defined conversion): [Wrong overload called when constructing from initializer_list inside parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47608388/580083)

Comment: Notice there is also copy constructor in overload set (so interpreted as `A(A{0})`).

Comment: @DanielLangr, thanks for the reference. It looks similar, but there GCC is wrong, diverging from Clang and MSVC due to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99273

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Clang & GCC are right, MSVC has a bug

This is [CWG 1589](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1589):

> #### 1589. Ambiguous ranking of list-initialization sequences
>
> **Section**: 16.3.3.2  [over.ics.rank]
> **Status**: CD4
> **Submitter**: Johannes Schaub
> **Date**: 2012-11-21
>
> [Moved to DR at the November, 2014 meeting.]
>
> The interpretation of the following example is unclear in the current
> wording:
>
> ```
> void f(long);
> void f(initializer_list<int>);
> int main() { f({1L});
> ```
>
> The problem is that ***a list-initialization sequence can also be a
> standard conversion sequence***, depending on the types of the elements
> and the type of the parameter, ***so more than one bullet*** in the list
> in 16.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank] paragraph 3 ***applies***:
>
> > [...]
>
> These bullets give opposite results for the example above, and there
> is implementation variance in which is selected.
>
> [...]
>
> **Proposed resolution (June, 2014):**
>
> This issue is resolved by the resolution of issue
> [1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467).

Which as per the resolution was resolved via [CWG 1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467):

> #### 1467. List-initialization of aggregate from same-type object
>
> [...]
>
> **Proposed resolution (June, 2014):**
>
> [...]
>
> 6. Move the final bullet of 16.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank] paragraph 3 to the beginning of the list and change it as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> ***even if one of the other rules in this paragraph would otherwise apply.*** [*Example*: ...  — *end example*]
>
> This resolution also resolves issues 1490, 1589, 1631, 1756, and 1758.

Particularly by re-ording the [[over.ics.rank]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3) such that [[over.ics.rank]/3.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.1) now applies for the OP's case, and takes precedence over the other rules of [[over.ics.rank]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3):

> List-initialization sequence `L1` is **a better conversion sequence** than
> list-initialization sequence `L2` **if**
>
> - (3.1.1) **`L1` converts to `std​::​initializer_­list<X>`** for some `X` **and `L2` does not**, or, if not that
> - (3.1.2) [...]
>
> **even if one of the other rules in this paragraph would otherwise apply**.

Compilers such as GCC and Clang has since back-ported DR 1467 to earlier standards (C++11 and C++14); Clang specifically [as of Clang 3.7](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html), and we can verify the CWG 1589 connection to OP's example as it is rejected by Clang 3.6 but accepted by Clang 3.7 ([DEMO](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/91v56vT11)).

MSVC, on the other, has seemingly has not implemented this change even as per the updated C++17 standard where it is no longer "just a" DR.