# Ignoring GCC "error: braces around scalar initializer for type" errors. Make them warnings

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, braces

I have a nagging problem with GCC compiler errors "error: braces around scalar initializer for type". I have seen others complaining about this, although they describe it as a warning ([gcc warning: braces around scalar initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462513/gcc-warning-braces-around-scalar-initializer))

I am compiling code which is not mine to edit, and I get a lot of these errors throughout the code.

Basic Pattern is:

```
struct t_
{
    float f;
    int i;
};

float f = { 0.3 };      //Compiler is all happy with this.
int i = {0};            //Compiler is all happy with this too.
t_ t1 = { 0.3, 0 };     //Compiler is all happy with this too.
t_ t2 = { {0.3}, 0 };   //Compiler ERROR: braces around scalar initializer for type 'float'
```

I know I can remove the braces {} around the float scaler to remove this error, but I do not want to modify the code in any way. Is there a flag I can give to GCC (currently using MinGW gcc 4.8.1). i.e. "std=c++03", or something to get these errors at least displayed as warnings.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you putting braces around scalar initializers *at all*? It seems very odd.

Comment: What compiler did this code work on previously?

Comment: According to the language grammar this is not a syntax error; *braced-init-list* may be *{ initializer-clause, initializer-clause, ... }*, and *initializer-clause* may be *braced-init-list*.  Can someone point out the clause that says the `t2` initialization is illegal?

Comment: The code was originally written and compiled with VxWorks Windriver Workbench for embedded hardware. It is now being compiled for Linux via gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe there is no such option. The construct you have is not meaning the same thing in the two cases - first one is an initialization of one structure, the second is a a strcuture containing a structure or array. Which of course `float` isn't.

You may be able to work around it with

```
struct t_
{
    struct 
    {
       float f;
    };
    int i;
};
```

At least clang is happy with that. As is g++. That may be easier than changing a lot of initialization statements with extra braces in them. But it is admittedly still a change to the source code. Unfortunately, I'm pretty certain that this is necessary.

Complete example that I was testing with:

```
struct t_
{
    struct 
    {
        float f;
    };
    int i;
};



t_ t2 = { {0.3}, 0 };


int main()
{
    t2.f = 7;
}
```

Edit:
If it's not at all possible to edit the source, you'll need to parse the source code, identify the incorrect braces and output "correct" code. The more I think about this, the less I believe that it's at all possible to fix without some sort of edit to the source. Or that it has ever compiled...

Comment: Thanks for your help. The end solution was to build a Perl script (pre-build update) to automatically correct this and other compiler issues (between WindRiver Workbench, and Linux GCC). Unfortunately I do not have control over the source code ( repeatable black box input to my system ). It would be interested if gcc is not compliant to the grammer: braced-init-list