# Why does clang emit these warnings?

Tags: c++, clang, default-arguments

The clang compiler emit warnings for the snippet below, as can be seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/609c0732db0de9ba).

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -O0 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:1:18: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
void point(int = {1}, int = {2}) {}
                 ^~~
main.cpp:1:29: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
void point(int = {1}, int = {2}) {}
                            ^~~

2 warnings generated.
```

Why is this?

```
void point(int = {1}, int = {2}) {}

int main(){
    point();
}
```

As far as I can tell, `{1}` and `{2}` are perfectly valid default arguments according to [[dcl.fct.default]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#1), [[dcl.fct]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#3) and [[dcl.init]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#1).

Comment: Well, it's only a warning, IMO this just means "hey, that's useless and looks weird, are you sure that's what you meant?".

Comment: @Quentin As this appears to be a perfectly valid code, there should no warning.

Comment: There are plenty valid snippets that trigger warnings -- invalid code triggers errors. `if(x = something());` is another one.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso if this is valid but misleading (or dangerous) the compiler can generate a warning (cf misleading indentation gcc warning)

Comment: @Quentin But there is no warning from clang for this `int i =  {1};`

Comment: Might be the same reasoning from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462768/4342498)

Comment: @NathanOliver Not anymore. GCC doesn't emit a warning for `int i = {1};` .

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Maybe they used to have that warning as well, and when they removed it for a normal variable initialization they forgot to do the same for default arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc warning: braces around scalar initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462513/gcc-warning-braces-around-scalar-initializer)

Comment: @João Afonso: "As this appears to be a perfectly valid code, there should no warning" - this is a rather strange thing to say. *Warnings* are diagnostic messages that are *typically* issued for *perfectly valid code* (well-formed code), which the compiler sees as "valid but suspicious". *Invalid* (ill-formed) code normally triggers *errors*, not warnings. Not every compiler follows this distinction precisely, but nevertheless that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Braces are typically used when initializing instances of structs, for example:

```
struct example {
  int member1;
  int member2;
};

example x = { 1, 2 };
```

Clang is telling you that your use of braces isn't "normal" for initializing a single value. This warning could help if you weren't familiar with the syntax for initializing values in C++, or perhaps if the types had previously been structs before a refactoring of some sort.

You can either stop using braces when initializing integers, or pass the `-Wno-braced-scalar-init` flag to the compiler to stop it reporting the warning.