# Warning from gcc: braces around scalar initializer, how to fix?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, kernel

At rewriting kernel driver I got this warning:

```
msm-cirrus-playback.c:545:2: warning: braces around scalar initializer
```

Read that this warning appears when I am declaring one structure's field in {}:

```
struct random_struct test = {
    { .name = "StackOverflow" },
    { .name = "StackExchange" },
};
```

But my structure have 2-3 fields in {}:

```
static struct device_attribute *opalum_dev_attr = {
    {
    .attr->name = "temp-acc",
    .show = opsl_temp_acc_show,
    .store = opsl_temp_acc_store,
    },
    {
    .attr->name = "count",
    .show = opsl_count_show,
    .store = opsl_count_store,
    },
    {
    .attr->name = "ambient",
    .show = opsl_ambient_show,
    .store = opsl_ambient_store,
    },
    {
    .attr->name = "f0",
    .show = opsl_f0_show,
    .store = opsl_f0_store,
    },
    {
    .attr->name = "pass",
    .show = opsl_pass_show,
    },
    {
    .attr->name = "start",
    .show = opsl_cali_start,
    },
};
```

This structure:

```
struct device_attribute {
    struct attribute    attr;
    ssize_t (*show)(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
            char *buf);
     ssize_t (*store)(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
             const char *buf, size_t count);
};
```

How can I fix this warning? Qualcomm kernels are building with -Werror flag, so this warning is critical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gcc warning: braces around scalar initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462513/gcc-warning-braces-around-scalar-initializer)

Comment: @SiegeX Nope, he had different reason

Comment: `.attr->name =` is not valid syntax for a designation in an initializer. Perhaps you meant `.attr.name =`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static struct device_attribute *opalum_dev_attr` means *declare opalum_dev_attr as static pointer to **struct device_attribute***

Your code is trying to initialize a static ***array*** of struct `device_attribute`

What you want is: `static struct device_attribute opalum_dev_attr[]` which means *declare opalum_dev_attr as static array of struct device_attribute*

Comment: he can assign the pointer with the array of the structs as well. As in my answer

Answer (score 0):

It is because you initialize the pointer to the struct not the struct itself.

you need to assign the reference to the struct for example by using compound literals

```
struct x 
{
    int a,b,c;
}a = {1,2,3};



void foo()
{
    struct x a = {1,2,3};
    struct x *b = {1,2,3}; // wrong warning here
    struct x *x = &(struct x){1,2,3}; // correct reference to the struct assigned (using compound literal
    struct x *y = (struct x[]){{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {4,5,6}, };
    struct x z[] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {4,5,6}, };

}
```